# Neo4jClient: Does it support timeout parameter for executing queries?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am using neo4j 1.9.4 community and soon will upgrade to 2.x. I know that neo4j can be configured with timeout in 2 ways as described [here](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/10/17/neo4j-setting-query-timeout/) 
But I wanna know if the second approach i.e. including max-execution-timeout in REST call header is supported by any of the Neo4jClient method so that I can pass that value as a parameter before returning my results? Also, will it be supported by future neo4j release?

The goal is to define a timeout for each query rather global setting.

Something like :

```
GraphClient
    .Root
    .StartCypher("root")
    .Match("root-[:HAS]->childs")
    .Return("childs")
    .Results(5000) // passing timeout value in ms
```

Answer (score 1):

At present, no, Neo4jClient doesn't have this capability.
Will it be supported? That depends on a few things, but as it's open source (https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient) you can always add it yourself and get it into the next release.

PS. For using against a 2.x db, you will want to look at the `.Cypher` so your query will look more like:

```
GraphClient.Cypher
    .Match("root-[:HAS]->child")
    .Return(child => child.As<ChildObj>())
    .Results();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Chris. Yes, I'd be happy to add it to the source code provided Neo4j would still continue to support that header in 2.x. I could not find any documentation on it. Thus, looking for an answer. Else, don't want to add something which would be obsolete in 2.x

Comment: Hey @BalvinderSingh, just asked on Twitter (https://twitter.com/CSkardon/status/510075807939977216) and Michael Hunger has confirmed that they still support the header in 2.x